# Using Az.Websites module to set up user assigned managed identity to pull image from ACR

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to configure my app service to use user assigned managed identity to pull image from ACR. I figured how to do it by using az cli tool.

```
az resource update --ids /subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<app-name>/config/web --set properties.acrUseManagedIdentityCreds=True

az resource update --ids /subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<app-name>/config/web --set properties.AcrUserManagedIdentityID=$clientId
```

For certain resons I cannot utilize az cli in my release pipelines. My question is if it would be possible to achieve the same by using Az.Websites, looks like Set-AzWebApp doesn't support this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet#using-azure-powershell-1), the current version of the Azure PowerShell cmdlets for Azure App Service do not support user-assigned identities.

You could instead try setting those properties with the [Set-AzResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/set-azresource?view=azps-6.6.0) cmdlet.